# NSAttributedString works on iPhone SE in simulator but not iPhone 7

Tags: ios, iphone, swift3, nsattributedstring

I set an attributed string which works fine in the simulator using iPhone SE but not iPhone 7. There is no error, it just doesn't show anything.

I'm also getting a warning on the attributes `Expression implicitly coerced from NSObject? to Any`

Here is my code:

```
let firstName = "Mark"

let welcomeAttributes = [ NSForegroundColorAttributeName: Constants.APP_TEXT_COLOR,
                                              NSFontAttributeName: Constants.APP_CELL_FONT ]

let userNameAttributes = [ NSForegroundColorAttributeName: Constants.APP_THEME_COLOR,
                                               NSFontAttributeName: Constants.APP_CELL_FONT ]

let unformattedUserFirstName = firstName

let userFirstName = NSAttributedString(string: unformattedUserFirstName, attributes: userNameAttributes)

let unformattedWelcome = "Welcome "

let welcome = NSAttributedString(string: unformattedWelcome, attributes: welcomeAttributes)

let welcomeString = NSMutableAttributedString()

welcomeString.append(welcome)

welcomeString.append(userFirstName)

self.welcomeLabel.attributedText = welcomeString
```

---

```
let welcomeLabel: UILabel = {
    let label = UILabel()
    label.backgroundColor = .white
    label.font = Constants.APP_CELL_FONT
    label.textColor = Constants.APP_TEXT_COLOR
    let welcomeAttributes = [ NSForegroundColorAttributeName: Constants.APP_TEXT_COLOR,
                              NSFontAttributeName: Constants.APP_CELL_FONT ]
    let unformattedWelcome = "Welcome"
    let welcome = NSAttributedString(string: unformattedWelcome, attributes: welcomeAttributes)
    let welcomeString = NSMutableAttributedString()
    welcomeString.append(welcome)
    label.attributedText = welcomeString
    return label
}()
```

---

```
static let APP_CELL_FONT = UIFont(name: "Muli", size: 12)
static let APP_TEXT_COLOR:UIColor = UIColor(red: 50.0/255.0, green: 50.0/255.0, blue: 50.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
static let APP_THEME_COLOR:UIColor = UIColor(red: 231.0/255.0, green: 76.0/255.0, blue: 60.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
```

These fonts are installed:

```
Muli
== Muli-Light
== Muli-ExtraLight
== Muli
```

To verify this I ran the following code in app delegate.

```
    for family: String in UIFont.familyNames
    {
        print("\(family)")
        for names: String in UIFont.fontNames(forFamilyName: family)
        {
            print("== \(names)")
        }
    }
```

Comment: Have iPhone 7 is simulator or device? Have you deleted the app from iPhone 7 and checked?

Comment: I am only using the simulator, I don't have an iPhone.

Comment: do you see the same issue when you reset content and settings in the simulator?

Comment: Yes, nothing changes. It is still blank.

Comment: Are you sure the font is valid and non-nil?

Comment: iPhone SE and iPhone 7 have different screen size. Is related? Is the label added? Constraints issue? If you don't use `NSAttributedString`, but simple `string`, does it work? Is the iOS version the same for both?

Comment: Yes to all those questions.

Answer (score 1):

This issue occur mainly because of font, if this is a custom font, then check the actual name of font.

Comment: The font appears to be properly installed, I edited my question to include this.

Comment: Does the print statement are from simulator or iPhone?. Also test for onething whether the below works.
    let welcomeLabel= UILabel();
    welcomeLabel.font = Constants.APP_CELL_FONT;
    welcomeLabel.textColor = Constants.APP_TEXT_COLOR;   welcomeLabel.text = "Hello";

Comment: It's all on simulator only. The "welcome" part does print on all phone simulations, just not the attributed part.

Comment: Is it a ttf or otf font?. 1) Check the font is check marked for target membership. 2) Check whether fonts are included as resources in your bundle. 3) Check custom fonts are included in your application plist